# Passing an array of objects to a partial - handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating

Im trying to pass an array of objects into a partial as an argument:

```
{{> partial [{title: "hello", year: "2015"}, {title: "hello2" year: "2015"}] }}
```

and then on the partial:

```
<div>

  {{#each this}}
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    <label>{{year}}</label>
  {{/each}}

</div>
```

... but nothing shows up.

Is there a way to pass array data to a partial?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you wanting to pass this data inline? I mean why not `{{>partial arrayData}}`?

Answer (score 6):

Create a helper that parses the JSON and wrap your partial with this context.

Template:

```
{{#getJsonContext '[{"title": "hello", "year": "2015"}, {"title": "hello2" "year": "2015"}]'}}
    {{> partial this }}
{{/getJsonContext}}
```

Note that the names are quoted as well as the values in the JSON string.

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getJsonContext', function(data, options) {
   return options.fn(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Credit: https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/228#issuecomment-20853985

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
{{> partial items=this.something }}
```

in

```
Handlebars.registerPartial(
    'partial', 
    "<div>{{#each items}}<label>{{title}}</label><label>{{year}}</label>{{/each}}</div>"
);
```

input:

```
{
    something: [{title: "hello", year: "2015"}, {title: "hello2", year: "2015"}]
}
```

Also, there is a problem in the JSON object.