# Pass JSON returned from Handlebars Helper as parameter into Handlebars Partial

Tags: handlebars.js, partial

I want to set up a partial to render a generic, customizable modal.  `{{> myModal }}`.

I want to customize the modal from the calling view by sending an object.

I have tried the approach as recommended here:  [Passing an array of objects to a partial - handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372693/passing-an-array-of-objects-to-a-partial-handlebars-js)

Here is my code from within the view which calls the partial:

```
{{# getJsonContext '
    {
        "id": "deleteModal",
        "title": "Are you sure?",
        "formId": "delete-form",
        "body": "Press Yes to delete this record.  Press No to cancel."
    }
'}}

    {{> myModal this }}

{{/ getJsonContext }}
```

Here is my helper:

```
getJsonContext: function(data, options) {
        console.log(data);                     <-- The result is correct.
        let jsonReturn = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsonReturn.title);         <-- The result is correct.
        return jsonReturn;
},
```

Here is my partial:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{ id }}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header bg-light">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="{{ formId }}" method="post">

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ body }}
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer rounded-bottom bg-light">

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the partial view to render the customized modal.

The partial does not seem to render at all.  When I "View Page Source" in the browser, in the place of all of the partial `<html>`, all it shows is `[object Object]`.

If I place the `{{> myModal this}}` *outside* of the helper, "View Page Source" shows all the modal's `<html>,` but naturally, the id, title, formId and body are all blank (null).

Comment: Look again at the `getJsonContext` helper in the answer you referenced. There is a very big difference between the `return options.fn(JSON.parse(data));` in that example and the return statement in yours.

Answer (score 0):

After racking my brain with lots of trial and error and research, I finally found out the problem.  I had to pass the JSON as a **named** parameter in the main view's call to the partial.  The syntax should have been:

```
{{> jeff-modal <anyVariableName> = getJsonContext }}
```

I finished up and made my generic `{{> jeff-modal }}` accept a list of buttons, which can be customized.

The modal is now useful as a generic, customizable, simple modal which can be rendered as a partial from within any view to require the user to press one of x-number of buttons to make a choice.

## Example

The main (calling) view has a list of journal entries (transactions) in date order.  For each transaction, there is a clickable "delete" icon.  The modal opens when the user presses the icon.  When the modal is opened, we need to know **which** transaction to delete.  We have its `_id`.

After setting up the table and columns in `<html>` and starting an `{{# each }}` iterator, the following is how the "delete" icon is set up for each transaction.  Notice how the `data-id`'s value is set to the transaction's `_id` property:

```
<!-- table stuff up here -->

{{# each transactions}}    

  <tr class="journal-entry-row">

  <!-- some `<td>`'s -->

     <span class="journalData">
       <a href='#' class="open-deleteDialog"
                data-id="{{this._id}}" data-backdrop="static"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">

                     <span class="material-icons md-24 md-dark">delete</span>

       </a>
     </span>

  <!-- more table stuff -->

{{/ each }}
```

The material-icons, above, can be found here:  https://material.io/icons/

"delete" is a trash can.

Below is the javascript to set the onclick for all the trash cans.  **Notice how the transaction's `_id` makes the trip from the `<html>` into the javascript *via* the `data-id` (above)**.  (I thought that was pretty clever, whoever thought of it.)

Also, since our custom modal was assigned an `id` of "delete-form", we can get it  to set the modal's `<form>` `action`.

Finally, a little CSS is added to highlight the row being deleted.

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-deleteDialog", function () {

     var myTransactionId = $(this).data('id');

     // Set form action to call delete with _id parameter
     $("#delete-form").attr("action", "/transaction/delete?_id=" + myTransactionId );

     // Highlight the selected row.
     $(this).closest(".journal-entry-row").addClass("table-warning");

});
```

Now, let's go back to the calling view after the end of the `<table>`.  This is where the modal is called within the handlebars helper block (but only when the trash can is clicked):

```
<!-- The Delete modal -->
{{# getJsonContext '
    {
        "id": "deleteModal",
        "title": "Are you sure?",
        "formId": "delete-form",
        "body": "Press \"Yes\" to delete this record.  Press \"No\" to cancel.",
        "buttons":
            [
                { "type": "submit", "onclick": "", "class": "btn btn-primary", "text": "Yes" },
                { "type": "button", "onclick": "removeHighlightEffect()", "class": "btn btn-secondary", "dataDismiss": "modal", "text": "No" }
            ]
    }'
}}

    {{> jeff-modal options = getJsonContext }}

{{/ getJsonContext }}
```

Here's the helper:

```
getJsonContext: function(data, options) {
        let jsonReturn = options.fn(JSON.parse(data));
        return jsonReturn;
},
```

Finally, the partial `{{> jeff-modal }}`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{ id }}">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header bg-light">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="{{ formId }}" method="post">

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ body }}
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer rounded-bottom bg-light">
                {{# each buttons }}
                    <button type = "{{ type }}" onclick = "{{ onclick }}" class = "{{ class }}" data-dismiss = "{{ dataDismiss }}" >{{ text }}</button>
                {{/ each }}
            </div>

        </form>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure whether I can call multiple instances of this modal from the same view with different titles, bodies, buttons, etc.  Some tweaking might be required for that, and I'm not going to worry about it until the need arises.